# EF 6 deletes object from collection when marked as deleted

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I follow this tutorial:

[EF 6 disconnected scenario](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/update-entity-graph-using-dbcontext.aspx)

```
    foreach (var foo in item.Foos)
    {
        if (foo.State == PocoState.Deleted)
        {
            ctx.Entry(foo).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        }
    }
    ctx.SaveChanges();
```

But I always get an InvalidOperationException because the 'foo' is deleted from item.Foos before calling ctx.SaveChanges();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't delete from a list while you are iterating that list. A `ToList` will solve the problem because you will iterate a "copy" instead of the list itself.

```
 foreach (var foo in item.Foos.ToList())
 {
    if (foo.State == PocoState.Deleted)
    {
       ctx.Entry(foo).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    }
 }
 ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: thank you, but can you explain why the code from the tutorial runs? The author doesn't call ToList() in the Foreach

Comment: That seems incorrect for me. I don't think it gonna work. Does that work for you?